# Gensim most similar word to vector

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am using the pretrained word vectors from Wikipedia, `"glove-wiki-gigaword-100"`, in Gensim. As [this example documentation](https://github.com/kavgan/nlp-in-practice/blob/master/pre-trained-embeddings/Pre-trained%20embeddings.ipynb) shows, you can query the most similar words for a given word or set of words using

```
model_gigaword.wv.most_similar(positive=['dirty','grimy'],topn=10)
```

However, I would like to query the most similar words to a **given vector**, specified as an array (of the same format as a word-vector from the pretrained model). For example, the result from adding or subtracting two word-vectors in the pretrained model, like

```
vec = model_gigaword['king']-model_gigaword['man']
```

Output: (for `vec`)

```
array([-0.696     , -1.26119   , -0.49109   ,  0.91179   ,  0.23077281,
       -0.18835002, -0.65568995, -0.29686698, -0.60074997, -1.35762   ,
       -0.11816999,  0.01779997, -0.74096   ,  0.21192   , -0.407071  ,
       -1.04871   , -0.480674  , -0.95541   , -0.06046999,  0.20678002,
       -1.1516    , -0.98955095,  0.44508   ,  0.32682198, -0.03306001,
       -0.31138003,  0.87721   ,  0.34279   ,  0.78621   , -0.297459  ,
        0.529243  , -0.07398   ,  0.551844  ,  0.54218   , -0.39394   ,
        0.96368   ,  0.22518003,  0.05197001, -0.912573  , -0.718755  ,
        0.08056   ,  0.421177  , -0.34256   , -0.71294   , -0.25391   ,
       -0.65362   , -0.31369498,  0.216278  ,  0.41873002, -0.21784998,
        0.21340999,  0.480393  ,  0.47077006, -1.00272   ,  0.16624999,
       -0.07340002,  0.09219003, -0.02021003, -0.58403   , -0.47306   ,
        0.05066001, -0.64416003,  0.80061007,  0.224344  , -0.20483994,
       -0.33785298, -1.24589   ,  0.08900005, -0.08385998, -0.195515  ,
        0.08500999, -0.55749   ,  0.19473001, -0.0751    , -0.61184   ,
       -0.08018   , -0.34303   ,  1.03759   , -0.36085004,  0.93508005,
       -0.00997001, -0.57282   ,  0.33101702,  0.271261  ,  0.47389007,
        1.1219599 , -0.00199997, -1.609     ,  0.57377803, -0.17023998,
       -0.22913098, -0.33818996, -0.367797  ,  0.367965  , -1.08955   ,
       -0.664806  ,  0.05213001,  0.40829998,  0.125692  , -0.44967002],
      dtype=float32)
```

How do I get the most similar words to `vec`?

Comment: I have updated my answer to a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly use this with `model_gigaword.wv.most_similar`

```
your_word_vector = np.array([-0.696, -1.26119, -0.49109, 0.91179, 0.23077281,
       -0.18835002, -0.65568995, -0.29686698, -0.60074997, -1.35762   ,
       -0.11816999,  0.01779997, -0.74096   ,  0.21192   , -0.407071  ,
       -1.04871   , -0.480674  , -0.95541   , -0.06046999,  0.20678002,
       -1.1516    , -0.98955095,  0.44508   ,  0.32682198, -0.03306001,
       -0.31138003,  0.87721   ,  0.34279   ,  0.78621   , -0.297459  ,
        0.529243  , -0.07398   ,  0.551844  ,  0.54218   , -0.39394   ,
        0.96368   ,  0.22518003,  0.05197001, -0.912573  , -0.718755  ,
        0.08056   ,  0.421177  , -0.34256   , -0.71294   , -0.25391   ,
       -0.65362   , -0.31369498,  0.216278  ,  0.41873002, -0.21784998,
        0.21340999,  0.480393  ,  0.47077006, -1.00272   ,  0.16624999,
       -0.07340002,  0.09219003, -0.02021003, -0.58403   , -0.47306   ,
        0.05066001, -0.64416003,  0.80061007,  0.224344  , -0.20483994,
       -0.33785298, -1.24589   ,  0.08900005, -0.08385998, -0.195515  ,
        0.08500999, -0.55749   ,  0.19473001, -0.0751    , -0.61184   ,
       -0.08018   , -0.34303   ,  1.03759   , -0.36085004,  0.93508005,
       -0.00997001, -0.57282   ,  0.33101702,  0.271261  ,  0.47389007,
        1.1219599 , -0.00199997, -1.609     ,  0.57377803, -0.17023998,
       -0.22913098, -0.33818996, -0.367797  ,  0.367965  , -1.08955   ,
       -0.664806  ,  0.05213001,  0.40829998,  0.125692  , -0.44967002])

model_gigaword.wv.most_similar(positive=[your_word_vector], topn=10)
```

```
[('vajiravudh', 0.7130449414253235),
 ('prajadhipok', 0.6764554381370544),
 ('andrianampoinimerina', 0.6474215984344482),
 ('jeongjo', 0.6449092626571655),
 ('taejong', 0.6352322697639465),
 ('rehoboam', 0.6319528818130493),
 ('injo', 0.6317901611328125),
 ('gojong', 0.6302404999732971),
 ('seonjo', 0.6272163391113281),
 ('elessar', 0.6250109672546387)]
```

**These results will be almost garbage, as expected. Read the reason below.**

---

One important point though. I see you are trying to find the words that are similar to the difference vector in the euclidean space of the word vectors. The difference between `king` and `man` results in a vector that is similar to the difference between `queen` and `woman` means that the length and direction of the difference vector encode the contextual difference between the 2 respective pairs of words.

**The literal position of that vector maybe garbage because by checking it in the euclidean space, you will anchor it on the origin. Both the difference vectors (King->Man and Queen->Woman) above are anchored on 'King' and 'Queen' respectively.**

The intuition you should have is that A->B and C->D may have similar vectors connecting them even though A, B and C, D may line in completely separate parts of the euclidean space, IF they have a similar contextual difference between them. This is what the vector space in a properly trained word2vec is encoding.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, could you clarify this with code? You can load the model easily if you have gensim with ```import gensim.downloader as api``` then ```model_gigaword = api.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-100")```. My doubts are  (1) how to go from the model to the (words, dims) matrix in an optimal way (in practice, there are 400,000+ words and 100 dimensions),  (2) how to perform the dot product fast like Gensim does (I think using numpy/scipy)

Comment: Check my updated answer, turns out there is a simpler method. Do let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: Ahh thanks that really clears it up. My actual use-case is to query something like vector['queen'] + vector['king']-vector['man'], which should yield a vector close to vector['woman']. Then with similarity search I would extract 'woman' as the top hit (or one of them). Do you think cosine similarity (which most_similar is using, I believe) is best for this? I have a feeling, as you hint, Euclidean distance may be more relevant

Comment: I believe cosine similarity will give you better results because word2vec, like you saw, encodes context in direction. Vectors which are in similar direction and with similar length  tend to be contextual/semantically similar. Meanwhile euclidean distances in a word2vec space do still hold meaning but I think cosine similarity would be a better measure to compare vectors.

Comment: Also, do mark the question if you think it solves your question. That would help others on SO looking for similar queries.